# How to change the cursor type from block to underline in Eclipse IDE for MacBookPro?

Tags: java, eclipse, web, cursor, project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2TSm.png) I am not able to replace blinking cursor to original vertical type.

I tried changing  it by function + Return key. But no update. There is also no provision of Insert key on Mac keyboard. Help me please.

Comment: I'm 99.5% certain it's because you changed the mode to e.g. insert mode or something similar - the question I marked this as duplicate of contains multiple answers about which modes exist and how to switch to and from. If it's not that, edit the question to expand a little bit (e.g. what 'mode' is listed in the bottom right in the status bar? 'Smart insert'?), and I can undo the 'duplicate of' mark.

Comment: NB: I bet it reads 'Overwrite'. Press Insert to change it back to normal mode. On a mac, which doesn't have an insert key, double click 'Overwrite' so that it switches back to Smart Insert. If it doesn't read 'Smart insert' but just 'Insert', you probably want to set it to smart insert. Open preferences, search for 'keys', and in keys search for 'toggle insert'. Then use that keyboard shortcut, or give it one, and use the shortcut.